# Cannot understand some c++

Tags: c++

I am looking at an example of the baby step giant steps algorithm in c++, I don't know c++, but I can understand most of the program, however there's two lines im just not sure what they do,

```
int powmod (int a, int b, int m) {
    int res = 1;
    while (b > 0)
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % m;
            --b;
        }
        else {
            a = (a * a) % m;
            b >>= 1;
        }
   return res % m;
}
```

Can someone please explain what the first `if` statement `(b & 1)` is checking, and also in the `else` statement `b >>= 1` why is there two `'>'` operators, is this just how you check greater/equal to in c++? Thanks

Comment: `if (b & 1)` checks whether `b` is odd (has its low-order bit set). `b >>= 1` shifts `b` right by one bit, and assigns the result back to `b`; it's roughly equivalent to `b = b / 2;` See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: "I don't know c++, but I can understand most of the program". There are a lot of good references on C++ syntax. You should open one. This is not a real programming question.

Comment: Specifically, look up bit manipulation. Both `&` (bitwise and) and `>>` (right-shift and by extension `>>=`) fall into that category.

Comment: If you are wondering why people use (b&1) and (b>>=1) instead of the much more explicit (0==(b%2)) and (b/=2)... so do I. Historically, when the compilers were dumber than programmers, it could run a bit faster. Nowadays, I would be curious to know if it achieves anything else than gratuitous obfuscation. In this specific case it is plain silly as the obvious and effective optimization (collapsing the if... else) is completely missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: >>= is the shift right assignment operator which performs the shift right operation on b and reassigns it to b.  >>= 1 basically divides b by 2.

It shifts all the bits 1 to the right.

eg if b in binary is 00000010 (2 in decimal), b >>= 1 would make b = 00000001 (1 in decimal).  another eg2: 00001110 (14) would be become 00000111 (7) etc  Do that again though and you lose precision: 00000111 (7) becomes 00000011 (3).

Answer (score 0):

It is [right shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) to perform bitwise operation.

```
b >>= 1;
```

Above statement means -

```
b = b >> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are bitwise operators. The '&' symbol represents AND which in that case will check the binary representation of 'b' with the binary representation of 1. '>>=' is also a bitwise operator called a right shift.